# AJAX: PHP function returns 1, but 'success' part says it returns 0

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I need a help with the below-given function. The function `mainApp.php` returns 1, but `Else` part of the `success IF` statement is executed. I have doubts regarding the correctness of an expression`function(html,msg)`. How to solve this problem?

**UPDATE (Working code):**

```
function click_function_ps() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'callpage.php?page=optim/mainApp.php',
        data: 'myParam='+$('#myParam').val(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(output){
            if(output.msg === 1){
                $('#myContainer').html(output.html);
            } else {
                $dialog.dialog('open');
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**mainApp.php**

```
 $html_code = '<table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td width="100%">
                        <div class="scrollbar" id="chart"><img class="displayed" src="ganttchart.php"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>';

            echo json_encode(array('msg' => 1, 'html' => $html_code));
```

Comment: Fyi, `data: {myParam: $('#myParam').val()}` would be better since otherwise *you* are responsible for properly encoding the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response returned is in the first argument. The second one is usually not interesting.

> ```
> success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
> ```
>
> A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR object.

I'd also suggest you to rename `html` to something more meaningful such as `data` or `response` and add `dataType: 'json'` to your ajax arguments. Then make your PHP script return `json_encode(array('msg' => 1, 'html' => $your_html_code))` and use `data.msg` and `data.html` in your function.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. Oh, and remove the `return false;` - returning a value from that function has no use.

Comment: And mainApp.php should contain something like this?:   $html_code = '<table width="100%">
   <tr>
    <td width="100%">
     <div class="scrollbar" id="chart"><img class="displayed" src="ganttchart.php"></div>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>';

  json_encode(array('msg' => 1, 'html' => $html_code));

Comment: You forgot the `echo` to actually output the JSON: `echo json_encode(...)`

Comment: In my updated post you can see my last version of a code. I don't know why but Else part is executed instead of IF.

Comment: You are using `=== 1` but your script sends an integer. Use `=== 1` instead.